# Appending CSS file to element and childs

Tags: jquery, html, css, children, dynamic-css

I am currently creating a library for some CSS styles (there are some that are defined by jQuery too, so feel free to use JavaScript/jQuery for the solution - I don't think it's possible with normal CSS either way).

I have some parts that are supposed to only be applied if a parent element with a specific class (in the example .style-container) exists.

Of course this is possible by adding the class in front of every CSS selector.

That takes a lot of data more that needs to be transferred though, so I thought maybe there is a possibility of applying a CSS-file and it's content just to a specific element and it's children instead of the whole document.

Imagine this CSS (far simplified):

```
h1 {
   color: #f00;
   border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
```

This HTML document (part inside the body):

```
<div class="style-container">
   <h1>This should be styled</h1>
</div>
<div>
   <h1>This should be standard style</h1>
</div>
```

And now maybe have some JavaScript/jQuery to load the file for just all the elements with the class and it's children.

**Note:**

There might appear new Elements through JavaScript/jQuery that haven't been there before and I don't really want to load the whole style again then, because that may take a lot resources to load then, in case the content changes very fast.

And waiting isn't an option either, because then the element wouldn't be styled for the time that's being waited.

**EDIT:**
To point out again: I am searching for a better option that the standard CSS children selector, that would work like this:

```
.style-container h1 {
   color: #f00;
   border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
```

I want this, because it uses a lot more data to be transferred from server to client. To understand this: I have a part of my code in minimalized form with the selector and without. The one with the selector needs 3698 characters, the version without the selector needs 2538 characters. That is a difference of 1160 characters. Or, in kB we have a difference of 3.61kB - 2.47kB = 1.14kB. That seems very little, but it is only a very small part of the code it's going to be. I am expecting the code to be ten times as big. That makes a difference of 11,4kB. In my opinion that is quite a big amount for mobile devices...

Comment: I think css is fast enough if you specify the selector correclty. Read this here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Writing_efficient_CSS

Comment: Yeah, CSS is fast enough. But I was more worried about the amount of data transferred, especially because of mobile devices. I want it to be as mobile-friendly as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From where I see it you're looking for "scoped CSS", which is defined [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/:scope), but unfortunately for you is [only available in Firefox](http://caniuse.com/#feat=style-scoped)

That said, the basic CSS solution is anyway the more performant. If you need to add a script, this script will also have some weight (even if not that big) and take CPU time which on mobile may also be of importance. You would be re-inventing the wheel not even making it a perfect circle...

Comment: Oh, right, I didn't think of the CPU-usage of the script... Yeah, that might take about the same time. The data transferred doesn't seem too big, so that should be okay then.

Comment: I didn't know if you were caring about time or file size. Definitely if you car about download time, the script solution might not be a solution : it would need an extra request to be downloaded (which is not just about the size, there are some incompressible steps) and more resources at runtime (especially as your CSS selector would be quite simple, it's very easy to be parsed), so I think you should definitely go for the CSS solution which is as far as I know the only supposed to be used for that purpose.

Comment: There already is a script being passed, so no additional request. But yeah, now I think so too...

Answer (score 0):

This is basic CSS.

To style a H1 which is the child (first level child) of an element (example uses div but div could be replaced with .style-container or any class / ID):

```
div > h1 {
    color: #f00;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
```

You could also simply use:

```
div h1 {
    color: #f00;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000; 
}
```

The latter would apply to ALL h1's within a div.

Comment: I asked the question, because I wanted to avoid this (I am currently using the second option). I would have to apply this to ALL selectors, which would cause the file to grow a lot, which again causes a lot more data to be transferred.

Comment: You might benefit then from looking into SASS, which can utilise nested styling.

Comment: @Callum > SASS anyway needs to be parsed either server-side or client-side in order to be rendered by the browser so that wouldn't solve the OP file weight issue.  Sass is facilitating dev, not improving performance in any way.

Answer (score 0):

In your case instead of Using script  to load style everytime for styling the element,better to use only with CSS.
Because css selector will load instantly when ever it saw the selector in the DOM.
Css:

```
div.style-container> h1{
   color: #f00;
   border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
```

`>` indicated immediate h1 after  the class `.style-container`.ie only children to it ,not all children to children.

```
div.style-container h1 {
    color: #f00;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
```

`Space` will read all the h1 elements under the class `.style-container`.ie it will consider children along with children to children.

Comment: I asked the question, because I wanted to avoid this (I am currently using the second option). I would have to apply this to ALL selectors, which would cause the file to grow a lot, which again causes a lot more data to be transferred.